# Django Action history changes log

Tags: python, django

I've been frantically looking around for an action history log for Django. Luckily I came across `LogEntryAdmin` which is great to an extent.

However, it doesn't show me the actual changes made. e.g. Changed Activity Description from *"this is for a park"* to *"this is for a cinema"*.

```
class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

date_hierarchy = 'action_time'

readonly_fields = [
    'action_time',
    'user',
    'content_type',
    'object_link',
    'change_message',
    'hello_world',
]

list_filter = [
    'action_time',
    'user',
    'content_type',
]

search_fields = [
    'object_repr',
    'change_message'
]


list_display = [
    'action_time',
    'user',
    'content_type',
    'object_link',
    'change_message',
    'hello_world',
]

def has_add_permission(self, request):
    return False

def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return request.user.is_superuser and request.method != 'POST'

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return False

def object_link(self, obj):
    if obj.action_flag == DELETION:
        link = escape(obj.object_repr)
    else:
        ct = obj.content_type
        link = u'<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
            reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (ct.app_label, ct.model), args=[obj.object_id]),
            escape(obj.object_repr),
        )
    return link
object_link.allow_tags = True
object_link.admin_order_field = 'object_repr'
object_link.short_description = u'object'

def queryset(self, request):
    return super(LogEntryAdmin, self).queryset(request) \
        .prefetch_related('content_type')


admin.site.register(LogEntry, LogEntryAdmin)
```

If anyone can send me in the right direction I'd be extremely grateful!

Comment: The specific changes are not logged, because the record could easily become massively large. If you want to have a log of specific changes, you can use logging or use a package such as [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion)